# Trying to get property of non-object for just one list on laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, object, collections, laravel-query-builder

I only get one list from my DB

```
        $postalls=
        DB::table(users)
        ->select('*')
        ->where('id','=',5)
        ->get();

return View('codo.postview')
                ->with('postalls', $postalls);
```

when I use below on postview.blade.php

```
{{$postalls[0]->comment}}
```

I got the error message

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I know I can fix the view problem by use

```
 @foreach($postalls as $postall)
   {{$postall->comment}}
 @endforeach
```

But I want to ask~

Can I not use the foreach function to fix the error message?

I also try below  but I got  the same error
Can I transfer the collection to object?

```
  $postalls=
    DB::table(users)
    ->select('*')
    ->where('id','=',5)
    ->get()
    ->first();

{{$postalls->title}}
```

use first() with or without get()
dd($postalls)
Got the same result~
[image]

My id come from the button pushed and sent to the controller

```
   public function postshow($table,$id)
    {

        $postallsold=
        DB::table($table)
        ->select('*')
        ->where('id','=',$id)
        ->get()
        ->first();
      dd($postallsold);
```

[image]

Comment: Your collection is empty, so there is no [0] or first element.    You need to check to make sure your query found something before you try to access it.

Comment: just check dd($postalls); like @Devon 's said. It is probably null.

Comment: @Devon I use the dd . The result is not empty as above I put the screen capture

Comment: @robspin, that doesn't match your  code at all.  In the code above, you have id of 5 hardcoded.  Can't really help you if you don't present it properly.

Comment: @Devon  thanks for your reply. Sorry for the misundersatanding~It is because id wihic I used is variable .I can choose any id to make the result. So I can use the id on any record. I repres my code on id='5' above again~

Answer (score 0):

I think you were almost there. Try using `first()` *instead* of `get()`.

```
DB::table('users')
->select('*')
->where('id', '=', 5)
->first();
```

This should return an instance of `StdClass` instead of a collection.

If you still get the same error, it could be that there is no record matching ID 5.

Comment: `get()->first()` is pretty much equivalent to `first()` in this query.  First gets the first result from the database,  get returns the entire result set in a collection in the database then first() returns the first item from that collection. When using `where('id')`, the result set will likely only have a max of one result anyways.

Comment: I got the same error if I use fisrt() without the get()~
Property [comment] does not exist on this collection instance. Still the collection?